# In SQL, how to select with alias as array?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, alias

I've been trying and Googling for quite some time now to find out how to get the following output as the result of a MySQL query:

```
Array
(
[id] => 85
[values] => Array(
                  [first_value] => 676
                  [second_value] => 383
                  [third_value] => 876
)          
)
```

One of my failed efforts as for the MySQL query:

```
select id, first_value as values[], second_value as values[], 
third_value as values[] from.....
```

What would be the right way to go?
Many thanks for your support, Louis.

Comment: You might get a better response rephrasing this as a PHP question rather than MySQL. Assuming you are using PHP?

Comment: You can use MySQL json_object function to build json, but then you have to perform json_decode in your PHP code to match the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no support for "arrays" in a result set. There are no arrays in MySQL.

You can produce a comma-separated string:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT_WS(',', first_value, second_value, third_value) AS `values`
...
```

But that's not an array. It's just a string that contains commas (or other symbol you choose). Then it's up to the caller to explode that string.

See [CONCAT_WS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) for documentation on that function.

Comment: Thanks. I think I need to rewrite my code to avoid needing the array.